# How to exclude specific styleCop rules permanently?

Tags: stylecop

I have some rules which i don't need to follow according to them , so i'm looking for a way - how to disable these specific rules from every project i'll make, from now on, in visual studio 2010.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

you can use a *parent settings file* that will be shared by multiple solutions. stylecop will search each parent directory in the path for settings files to apply. put one in a common parent directory.

or you can use a *global settings file* which goes in the same directory as StyleCop.dll.

details here:

http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sharing%20StyleCop%20Settings%20Across%20Projects